# Is every program is equivalent to a Push Down Automata?

Tags: automata

so I was reading about [stack-organized computer](http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/gatecse/en-gatecse-chp159.html). Does a stack-organized computer implies that every program is equivalent to (and not more powerful than) a  Push Down Automata?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to give a self-contained definition of what you mean by a "stack-organized computer"?  For example, can the program access memory directly by address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The class of languages recognised by pushdown automata is the class of context-free languages, whereas the class of languages recognised by Turing machines is the class of Turing-recognizable (aka recursively enumerable) languages. All context-free languages are recognisable but the converse does not hold.